Raspberry Pi Bluetooth Intercom Project Advice
I am trying to build an intercom for several Bose QC35 headsets. I have a raspberry pi (Zero 2 W) running the latest bookworm (lite) distro; with 3 broadcom USB bluetooth adapters.
After much struggling, I can connect the headsets in HFP mode to each adapter, and create links between one headset source and another headset sink using pipewire. My plan was to use a python script to handle the connection and linking dynamically so that headsets could disconnect, and reconnect freely to any available adapter. Eventually a small screen would handle new headset pairings.
I have had to jump through many hoops just to get the headsets connected manually, and in HFP mode. For example, bluetoothctl reports the headset is available, when it is not even powered on, and the wireplumber commands for connecting to the HFP profile do not work, so I have to use pactl. Another issue I have is that the audio quality is really poor (clicks, skips, delays, etc) for just two headsets connected to each other. I have tried modifying the sampling frequency and quantum in pipewire and wireplumber, but nothing seems to improve the quality. Is the Raspberry pi zero powerful enough to handle this?
Is there someone who is familiar with linux bluetooth and audio that could provide help on this project? Is what I am trying to do reasonable? Am I going about it the right way?

Not trying to discourage you at all, but if I were doing this I think I'd look at wifi instead of Bluetooth - due to range limitations of BT. There's a project that uses RPi withmumble software to make a "home" intercom system.

Thanks for the reply. This will be a short range intercom, such as within a vehicle. Think one hub, multiple headsets.
